# How to resize an image using imageio?

Tags: image, python-imaging-library, numpy-ndarray, python-imageio

Consider an image `img` of type `imageio.core.util.Array`.

The shape of `img` is  `(256, 256, 3)`. I want to resize it to `(128, 128, 3)`.

I tried at least the following three:

```py
img.resize(img_res, pilmode="RGB")
```

```py
img.resize(img_res)
```

```py
img = cv2.resize(img, self.img_res)
```

Here `img_res = (128, 128)`.

None of them worked well. How can I resize my image to the desired size?

Comment: Please try and improve your code so it is **complete** and **runnable** in alignment with Stack Overflow **MCRE** https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 18):

According to the [documentation on `imageio.core.util.Array`](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/devapi.html#imageio.core.Array), `Array` is "a subclass of `np.ndarray` [...]". Thus, when calling `resize` on some `img` of type `Array`, the actual call goes to [`np.ndarray.resize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html) – which **IS NOT** [`np.resize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html)! That's important here.

From the documentation on `np.ndarray.resize`:

> **Raises:**
>
> **ValueError**
>
> If `a` does not own its own data [...]

That's why, some code like

```py
import imageio

img = imageio.imread('path/to/your/image.png')
img.resize((128, 128))
```

will fail in that way:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    img.resize((128, 128))
ValueError: cannot resize this array: it does not own its data
```

That error seems to be bound to the `Array` class, because the following code also fails with the same error message:

```py
from imageio.core.util import Array
import numpy as np

img = Array(np.zeros((200, 200, 3), np.uint8))
img.resize((128, 128))
```

Obviously, the `Array` class only stores a view to some not directly accessible NumPy array, maybe some internal memory buffer!?

Now, let's see possible workarounds:

Actually, using `np.resize` like

```py
import imageio
import numpy as np

img = imageio.imread('path/to/your/image.png')
img = np.resize(img, (128, 128, 3))
```

is not a good choice, because `np.resize` is not designed to properly resize images. So, the result is distorted.

Using OpenCV works fine for me:

```py
import cv2
import imageio

img = imageio.imread('path/to/your/image.png')
img = cv2.resize(img, (128, 128))
```

Keep in mind, that OpenCV uses BGR ordering, while imageio uses RGB ordering – that's important when also using `cv2.imshow` for example.

Using Pillow also works without problems:

```py
import imageio
from PIL import Image

img = imageio.imread('path/to/your/image.png')
img = Image.fromarray(img).resize((128, 128))
```

Finally, there's also `skimage.transform.resize`:

```py
import imageio
from skimage.transform import resize

img = imageio.imread('path/tp/your/image.png')
img = resize(img, (128, 128))
```

Pick one that best fits your needs!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.8.5
imageio:       2.9.0
NumPy:         1.19.5
OpenCV:        4.5.1
Pillow:        8.1.0
scikit-image:  0.18.1
----------------------------------------
```