# How to resize images with imageio to get proper ICO files?

Tags: python, image, ico, python-imageio

I want to save ICO files from images. `imageio` is working perfectly, but for horizontal images, it gave me an error.

This is my code:

```
import imageio
image = imageio.imread('image.png')
imageio.imwrite("image.ico", image)
```

Comment: what error did it give you?

Comment: @PrabhatKumarSahu It didn't give me any error. The square converted images open without any error. But in the case of horizontal images, I am not able to open that. Please suggest any easy way to resize them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, you have problems opening the resulting ICO files, because the software you use simply expects square images of certain size(s) when opening ICO files!? Unfortunately, it seems that [`imageio.imwrite`](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userapi.html#imageio.imwrite) saves ICO files with only setting the larger dimension to default 16, 24, ... pixels, when feeding a non-square image. Suppose, we have such an image:

[image: Input]

And, we have some test code like this:

```py
import imageio

# Read image
img_io = imageio.imread('image.png')

# Write ICO image
imageio.imwrite('image.ico', img_io)
```

The resulting `image.ico` has six images with dimensions `16 x 13`, `24 x 19`, and so on.

If you want to resolve that, you should properly resize your image beforehand to get a square image. Actually, resizing images can be quite difficult when using `imageio`. Please, see [this recent Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65733362/11089932) for some details. If you simply want to have a square image without keeping the aspect ratio, you might want to use [`skimage.transform.resize`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.resize):

```py
import imageio
from skimage.transform import resize

# Read image
img_io = imageio.imread('image.png')

# Resize image
img_io = resize(img_io, (200, 200))

# Write ICO image
imageio.imwrite('image.ico', img_io)
```

Now, the resulting `image.ico` has six images with dimensions `16 x 16`, `24 x 24`, and so on.

If you want to keep the aspect ratio of your image, you'd need to add proper borders to your image. There's [this helpful Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11142851/11089932) on that issue. You could also add fancy, transparent borders solely using NumPy:

```py
import imageio
import numpy as np

# Read image
img_io = imageio.imread('image.png')

# Add transparent borders to image
h, w = img_io.shape[:2]
img = np.zeros((w, w, 4), np.uint8)
img[30:h+30, :, :3] = img_io
img[30:h+30, :, 3] = 255

# Write ICO image
imageio.imwrite('image.ico', img)
```

Now, the resulting `image.ico` even has seven images with dimensions `16 x 16`, ..., `256 x 256`, since the modified image is large enough.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.8.5
imageio:       2.9.0
NumPy:         1.19.5
scikit-image:  0.18.1
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reshape()` so your code could become something like

```
import imageio
image = imageio.imread('image.png')
M, N, C = image.shape
image = image.reshape((N, M, C)) # new shape here, I inverted M and N
imageio.imwrite("image.ico", image)
```

Watch out, however, the number of pixels cannot change with `reshape`, that is the total number, in this case, is `M * N`, once you reshape, the new number of pixels must be the same.
If you want to change it, you can use `slicing`, there are examples [in the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html)